Raspberry Pi 4 Ubuntu Server 24.04 Wifi Not Working
I previously had 22.04 installed on a raspberry pi 4, ran through release upgrades to get to 24.04 and wifi stopped working. Wiped and used rpi imager for a clean install and wifi still doesn't work.
I also have a raspberry pi 5 and wifi is working fine on that with 24.04
I have also booted from raspberry pi os on the pi 4 to see if wifi works and it does
Has anyone experienced this? Is there a known issue?

Does this answer your question? My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?

I noticed the same issue on an RPi3. There is something broken with Ubuntu 24.04, as WiFi works just fine with Ubuntu 23.10. On 24.04, the system can see access points just fine, I can see the handshake on my access point, but then the system just disconnects and thinks no password was supplied. Interestingly, I got the same issue in latest Debian as well, so whatever the issue is, it's shared by both Ubuntu and Debian.
